# Truncated SVD implementation in Java

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I need the Truncated SVD implementation in java.
I need to pass a matrix of doubles and an integer value representing the rank where to filter out noise. In output i need a filtered matrix of doubles.

Is there something ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) has SVD, lookup `cern.colt.matrix.linalg.SingularValueDecomposition`

I think that [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) has its port too